# Excel data extractation remove words from cells and replace in another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, data-mining

[image: Company Type]

I have data in a column called "company" it lists 3000 companies along with the company type - whether it is LLC, LP, Corp, etc. 
The format is like this: Microsoft_LLC_LLC. I want to remove the LLC portion and put it in another column called lets say company type. Any ideas? Much appreciated. An Image of example of data set is posted.

Comment: How do you want Excel to recognize company type? Is that always the last "word" in the cell after a space ` ` or underscore `_`?

Comment: for anything that's a limited partnership its either space _LP or just _LP for LLC its LLC_LLC or _LLC, The problem is that each one is different. Is ther a way to apply logic that said remove characters "LP" "LLC" "Other" "Corp" etc?

Comment: No. As far as you have "etc" in your list you can't.  You need to clarify your rule before starting to write formulas.

Comment: Especially if it will always be at the end of the string, you can create a list of all the types you want removed; then check that list against your string.  You also need to order things correctly in case of situations where one type is found within another type.  For example, you would want to have LLC_LLC listed before _LLC or LLC